# Django getting (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get') after submitting a form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am studying django recently, and I met problem,

```
Internal Server Error: /event_edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/CalendarProject/cencal/views.py", line 107, in event_edit
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 393, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 258, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This error message appeared while doing `form.is_valid()`, but I can't know what is the problem. There was surely no problem with form field values.

If you need any additional informations for this, I am ready to do it.

**event_edit view**

```
def event_edit(request, pk=None):
    pk2=0
    if pk==None:
        if request.method == "POST":
            pk2 = int(request.POST.get('pk', None))
        else:
            pk2 = int(request.GET.get('pk', None))
    else:
        pk2 = pk
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=pk2)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EventForm(request.POST.get('form'))
        if form.is_valid():
            event = form.save(commit=False)
            event.author = request.user
            event.save()
            jsonres = JsonResponse({"res": "successful"})
            jsonres.status_code = 200
            return jsonres
            # return render(request, 'cencal/index.html', {'sidebarContent':render_to_string('cencal/detailevent.html', {'event': event})})
            # return redirect('detailevent', pk=event.pk)
        else:
            print(form.errors.as_json())
            jsonres = JsonResponse({"error": form.errors.as_json()})
            jsonres.status_code = 599
            return jsonres
    else:
        print("else")
        form = EventForm(instance=event)
        return render(request, 'cencal/eventform.html', {'form':form, 'edit':"true", 'pk':pk2})
```

**template javascript function to submit form**

```
function makeEvent(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var year = event.target.querySelector("#id_date").value.slice(0,4);
            var month = event.target.querySelector("#id_date").value.slice(5,7);
            var day = event.target.querySelector("#id_date").value.slice(8,10);
            var form = $("#eventform");
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: {'form' : form.serialize(), 'pk' : form.attr("pk"), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                success: function(response){
                    console.log("makeEvent() successful");
                    console.log(response);
                    refreshCalendarAjax(year, month);                         
                    listevent(year, month, day);
                    //아래 메시지 make/edit별로 따로 출력해야 함.
                    document.getElementById("sidebar").insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', '<div class="info">일정 등록 성공!</div>' );
                },
                error: function(data){
                    if (data.status == 599) {
                        listevent(year, month, day);
                        errors = JSON.parse(data.responseJSON.error);
                        errors['__all__'].forEach(function(error){
                             document.getElementById("sidebar").insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', error['message'] );
                        })
                    } else {
                        alert("code:"+data.status+"\n"+"message:"+data.status+"\n"+"error:"+data.error);
                    }
                },
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure, wait a sec

Comment: Normally you use the full `request.POST`, so `EventForm(request.POST)`, not a single item, since that is a string. Can you share the form as well (and perhaps the template)?

Comment: I uploaded the code. You might confused about their name difference, but it is intentional.

Comment: you need to deserialize it with `EventForm(QueryDict(request.POST['form']))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Django form requires a dictionary-like object as data, like `request.GET` and `request.POST`, not a string. Normally therefore you construct a form with:

```
form = EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Since a HTTP request is basically text, `request.POST['form']` will *always* be a string, not a dictionary, not even if you pass a JSON encoded blob to the the `form` key.

In case you serialize this, you need to de-serialize it, for example with:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

# …

form = EventForm(QueryDict(request.POST['form']))
```

Comment: It worked, I musted have read about form constructor :( thx!